# Bootstrap no padding beetween button and col-md-12

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I started to do a Bootstrap layout, but I noticed there is not any padding after the buttons and my panel stays below without the use of margin or padding.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwzohvxx/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <main-contents>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>title</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="headline-date">Tuesday, January 27, 2012 4:00pm</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add
               </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>test
               </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>Start
               </button>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#meeting-events">
                      test</a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="meeting-events" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#executive-action">
                      test</a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="executive-action" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#hearings">
                      test</a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="hearings" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        content 2
      </div>
    </main-contents>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not added any margin or padding.

```
button{
  width:80px;
  margin:20px;
}
.col-md-12{
  margin-top:50px;

}
```

Here is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/1upjc3yy/)